# NGinx Domain name redirects

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, domain, redirect

Lets say I have a website named `xyz.co`, I also have other domain names with the same prefix like `xyz.com, xyz.it, xyz.co.it`

Right now nginx works fine with `server_name xyz.co` in `nginx.conf` in `port 80` I would want all the other domains to redirect to `xyz.co` also I would want `www.*` versions of the above to redirect to `xyz.co`. How can I get this? Is this nginx webserver level changes? or I need to make this changes in `DNS`?

Comment: [Server names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  www.xyz.co xyz.com xyz.it xyz.co.it www.xyz.com www.xyz.it www.xyz.co.it;
        rewrite   ^  http://xyz.co$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  xyz.co;

        ....................
        ....................
        ....................
}
```

You can remove the `permanent` flag from rewrite directive if you want a 302 redirect instead of a 301.

Answer (score 3):

```
server {
    server_name ~^(?:www\.)?xyz\.(?:com|(?:co\.)?it)$;
    return http://xyz.co$request_uri;
}
```

or more effective:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xyz.com www.xyz.com
                xyz.it www.xyz.it
                xyz.co.it www.xyz.co.it;

    return http://xyz.co$request_uri;
}
```

- http://nginx.org/r/server_name
- http://nginx.org/r/return
- man pcresyntax
- man pcrepattern

Comment: although your answer was immensely helpful, since I already had a server block with lots of directives below, I was not sure what a return statement would do. @Ellimist answer clarified that.

Answer (score -1):

Documentation http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule

```
if ($http_host ~* "(www\.)?xyz\.(com|(co\.)?it)"){
  rewrite ^(.*)$ http://xyz.co/$1 break;
}
```

This will need testing and modifying to taste, but some quick tests show it should do what you need.

**UPDATE** per reference provided by VBart this: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html is a much better method, for achieving what you require, see his answer provided.

Comment: **This is a wrong, cumbersome, and ineffective way.** (c) http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html

Comment: cumbersome and ineffective I can agree with given the provided link showing a much better way to achieve this, wrong is debatable as the method works; in any event answer updated.

Comment: upvoting to negate the downvotes. This method might be wrong but it pointed me in right direction...